# Having a problem properly getting information from canvas and sending information to discord through webhook with node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord, fetch

So I am trying to send data from canvas's api using a GET and use that information and send a POST from the same endpoint to discord using node fetch. I can receive data from canvas without issue and I console log to make sure I have to right data, but I can't seem to get any information to discord. I am using discords webhooks and I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

````
fetch(url + `courses/${course}/discussion_topics` , {
    method: "GET",
    headers : {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer <auth token>',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
    
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => { 
       
    console.log(data[0].id);
    console.log(data[0].title);
    console.log(data[0].message);
}
 ) 
  .then(fetch("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/893327519103746149/<webhooktoken>", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
   body: {content: 'hello world'}
    
}))
.catch(err => console.log(err))

});```
````

Comment: `then(fetch(....))` - this will immediately call the `fetch` function. You probably meant to write: `then(() => fetch(....))`. Alternate option is to call the `fetch` function inside the callback function of second `then` method.

Comment: @Yousaf I tried both and still have nothing coming from it.

Comment: @Zboyz, did you `.then()` the the second `fetch()` after to get the response data?

Comment: @ikhvjs Yeah I just tried that and didn't work. I it's something wrong with the second fetch for sure though. Because if I do a curl request I get messages.

Comment: @Zboyz, typo ??: `body: {conent: 'hello world'}`  content?? not conent?? Show us your curl?

Comment: @ikhvjs I fixed the type already, but nothing came of it. curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\": \"Canvas-Bot\", \"content\":\"hello\"}" "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/893327519103746149/<my webhook>" It's CMD im on windows

Comment: @Zboyz, your curl body is different from your js code body. Are you sure you make the same request?

Comment: I have already used header content type and tried username  and content, but still don't work @ikhvjs

Comment: @Zboyz, no error message from the fetch? One more thing I think you can try is `method: "post",` change it to `POST` in uppercase instead.

Comment: No good unfortunately. @ikhvjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, just in case you have some typo or misunderstanding.

Also, you need to JSON.stringyify your body.

Please try the example below:

```js
fetch(url + `courses/${course}/discussion_topics`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer <auth token>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data[0].id);
    console.log(data[0].title);
    console.log(data[0].message);
  })
  .then(() =>
    fetch(
      "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/893327519103746149/<webhooktoken>",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: "Canvas-Bot",
          content: "hello world",
        }),
      }
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log({ data });
      })
  )
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Another approach would be in async/await. I think it is cleaner.

```js
(async function main() {
  try {
    const res1 = await fetch(url + `courses/${course}/discussion_topics`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer <auth token>",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    const data1 = await res1.json();
    console.log(data1);

    const res2 = await fetch(
      "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/893327519103746149/<webhooktoken>",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: "Canvas-Bot",
          content: "hello world",
        }),
      }
    );

    const data2 = await res2.json();
    console.log(data2);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: In the `.then()` version, is there not a missing `return` before the second `fetch()`? Either add `return` or purge the function's curly braces.

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes this did it! The first one I had trouble grabbing data from my .then()'s so I used the second method instead, but both fixed the reason why I wasn't fetching though. Thank you.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, If you want to return the result of the second fetch, yes. we should add a `return`.

Comment: @ikhvjs, it's not a case of wantintg to. Without a `return` (or omission of curly braces), `res` will not be delivered to `.then(res => res.json())`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, Thanks for pointing out. I didn't notice I made a mistake. I corrected it.